# How to show an array

Tags: c

I've got this:

```
int i, j, w;
char *array[50];

int main ()
{
    array[1]= "Perro";
    array[2]= "Gato";
    array[3]= "Tortuga";
    array[4]= "Girafa";
    array[5]= "Canario";
    array[6]= "Rata";
    array[7]= "Leon";
    array[8]= "Tigre";
    array[9]= "Rinoceronte";
    array[10]= "Mosquito";
    for (i=1; i<11; i++)
    {

        printf("El elemento %i es %s \n", i, array[i]);
    }
    printf("Escoja el elemento deseado");
    scanf("%i", &w);

    int c;
    scanf("%i",&c);
    return i;
}
```

Now I want something like this: printf("Desired Element %c, array[w]); but it fails, why?

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("Desired Element %c", array[w]);
```

will try to print a character (%c), but it will fail since array[w] contains a string.

Try using %s instead:

```
printf("Desired Element %s", array[w]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't print the friend name (a string) as character (`%c`), use `%s`.

Also, arrays in C start at index 0, making them start at 1 instead is weird and might make it easier to confuse yourself and access past the end.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it's not `%c` but `%s` for strings

`printf("Desired Element %d\n", array[w]);`

Don't forget to check wether `w` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

the `%c` element in your debug string prints a character. If you want to print the string try:

```
printf("Desired Element %s", array[w]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf("Desired Element %s, array[w])` instead of with %c. You're printing a string, not a character.

Answer (score 0):

There are many oddities in the program. Here is a cleaned-up version.

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* necessary for printf/scanf */

#define ARRAY_LENGTH 10  /* use a constant for maximum number of elements */

int main ()
{
    /* Declare all variables inside main(), at the very top. Nowhere else. */
    int i;
    int desired;  /* use meaningful variable names, not x,y,z,etc  */
    char *array[50];


    array[0]= "Perro";  /* arrays start at index 0 not 1 */
    array[1]= "Gato";
    array[2]= "Tortuga";
    array[3]= "Girafa";
    array[4]= "Canario";
    array[5]= "Rata";
    array[6]= "Leon";
    array[7]= "Tigre";
    array[8]= "Rinoceronte";
    array[9]= "Mosquito";

    for (i=0; i<ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) /* keep the loop clean */
    {
        printf("El elemento %i es %s\n\n", i+1, array[i]);  /* instead, add +1 while printing */
    }

    printf("Escoja el elemento deseado: ");
    scanf("%i", &desired);
    getchar(); /* discard new line character somehow */

    printf("El elemento %i es %s\n", desired, array[desired-1]);



    getchar(); /* wait for key press before exiting program */
    return 0; /* always return 0 */
}
```